# image inside of div looks out of it

Tags: html, image, position

I'm trying to fit an `image` inside a `div`. I think that's a easy thing to do but i don't understand why the `image` is half out of the `div`.

That's my html:

```
<div class="bar">
    <img src="images/bar.png" />
</div>
```

My css:

```
.bar {
    height:10px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.bar img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/502totnb/) to show what i try to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to the image.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/502totnb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default vertical alignment on the image:

```
.bar img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/502totnb/2/)**